# Could someone add a hyphen to the legalstatus tag?

Tags: support, status-completed

I was planning on creating `legal-status` as a new tag, then moving the four `legalstatus` questions over to it and letting the original expire. But, the system considers the two to be the same and will not allow `legal-status` to be created.

Would someone please rename `legalstatus` to `legal-status`?

Which moderator privilege allows this kind of edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple rename which can be performed by any Moderator♦. Good catch. Done.